# Probability of exit from compact set

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I have a continuous real valued diffusion $\{ X_t \}_{t\ge0 }$ that is contained in a compact set $[a,b] $of $\mathbb{R}$, where $a > 0$ and. Define the stopping times
\begin{equation}
\tau_c=\inf \{ t \colon X_t \le c \}\qquad \text{ and } \qquad\tau_d=\inf \{ t \colon X_t \ge d \}
\end{equation}
I have by some calculation that for any $a<c<X_0<d<b$, $\mathbb{E}(\tau_c \land \tau_d)< \infty$. This means that $X_t$ exits from every compact subinterval of $(a,b)$ in finite expected time.

But why this implies $\mathbb{P}(\tau_c \land \tau_d < \infty)=1$? How can I show it?

Comment: If a nonnegtative random variable has finite expectation, it is finite a.s.

Comment: @Fnacool Yes, this is the problem. But how can I show it?

Comment: If it were infinite on a set of positive measure, would its expectation be finite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Theorem** Let $X$ be a nonnegative random variable. If $\mathbb E(X)<\infty$, then $\mathbb P(X<\infty)=1$.

*Proof* Assume on the contrary that $\mathbb P(X<\infty)<1$, or equivalently, $\mathbb P(X=\infty)>0$. Then
$$
\mathbb E(X)\ge\infty\cdot P(X=\infty)=\infty,
$$
a contradiction.
QED.